# How to select all record from an association in active admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, associations, activeadmin

I have some models like this:

```
class Sponsored < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many  :sponsored_sports
  has_many  :sports,
            through: :sponsored_sports,
            class_name: 'Sport',
            source: 'sport'
  ...
end
```

this is sport model:

```
class Sport < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :sponsored_sports
  ...
end
```

Currently, in sponsored active admin page, I create sponsored sport one by one by this code:

```
form do |f|
    f.inputs "Details" do
      ...
      f.has_many :sponsored_sports, heading: '', allow_destroy: true do |e|
        e.input :sport_id, as: :select, :collection => Sport.order('rank'), :label_method => :name, :value_method => :name, :include_blank => false
      end
    end
    f.actions
  end
```

But now I just want to add more option for users to select all sport at once by clicking on a checkbox, for example: `select all`. So how can I do it in active admin? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a button or link in the `f.has_many` form and make a javascript so when this link is clicked you can programmatically add all values to the select.

Or you can send a new param to the form like `select_all` and make the association when updating or creating the model in the active_admin controller section:

```
controller do
    def update
        super
        *check the params and make the association*
    end
end
```